# UIViewTransitionfromView: will never work and displays only second image

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am running mad not understanding the weird behavior of UIViewTransitionfromView: the second view is displayed at first with no animation. Here's the code:

```
UIImageView *backstar=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 205, 205)];
    backstar.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"backstar.png"];

UIImageView *star=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 205, 205)];
star.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];

UIView *containerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 205, 205)];
containerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
[containerView addSubview:backstar]; // if I don't do this nothing happens, container view stays f*** deep black
[containerView addSubview:star];

//if i remove the animation line, star is displayed of course, on top of backstar

[UIView transitionFromView:star toView:backstar  duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished){} ];
```

where the hell is my mistake? It should be possible not to delete the imageViews but show/hide them, as said in Apple doc!

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your post where you have this code.  I found that it doesn't work if you have it all in viewDiLoad or viewWillAppear. You need to get the first view in and visible (in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear) and then add the second view and do the transition in another method (which could be called with a button or performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:). Also, if you want to go from star to backstar, then star should be added to the view first, and backstar only when you want to do the transition. This is what worked for me:

```
@implementation TransitionTestViewController
@synthesize star,backstar;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.backstar=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 205, 205)];
    backstar.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"backstar.png"];
    self.star=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 205, 205)];
    star.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:star];
    //[self performSelector:@selector(flipViews:) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01];
}

-(IBAction)flipViews:(UIButton *) sender {
    [self.view addSubview:backstar];
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.star toView:self.backstar  duration:2.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews |UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I call all this in an independent method, this is why I do not call another one and that the variables are defined inside it ( of course I could have done it in a different way). Anyway I will try the same as you, and will tell as soon as I can. I also see you don't use any containerView.

Comment: It worked with or without a container view, but since the code is split over two methods, you will need to have an ivar or property for containerView.

Comment: OK it works now, but only with a container view otherwise the main view flips as well.

Comment: In fact the problem is still there... it works only with my star view loaded in viewDidLoad, otherwise star doesn't even appear onscreen. Nice flip from backstar, that's all. ?

Comment: Where does it not work -- where else are you trying to load star view?

Comment: in a method that calls flipViews. I think I will try to make an animation with it, and flip views on completion, since what I want is star to appear shortly before it flips. anyway thx for you help! much appreciated